# Need help making an approximation of Euler's constant

Tags: javascript, math

It's very close but just one number off. If you can change anything here to make it better it'd be appreciated. I'm comparing my number with `Math.E` to see if I'm close.

```
var e = (function() {
    var factorial = function(n) {
        var a = 1;
        for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            a = a * i;
        }
        return a;

    };
    for (var k = 0, b = []; k < 18; k++) {
        b.push(b.length ? b[k - 1] + 1 / factorial(k) : 1 / factorial(k));
    }
    return b[b.length - 1];
})();
document.write(e);document.write('<br />'+ Math.E);​
```

My number: 2.7182818284590455
`Math.E`:    2.718281828459045

Comment: This looks pretty good, though if you want a really interesting way to stochastically estimate the value of e, check out this article http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2685243?uid=3739656&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21100837652421

Comment: What exactly is the problem? As far as limited precision those numbers look the same.

Comment: Well, Wolfram Alpha suggests that the final digit in OP's representation of e should be 2, not 5.  Then again, it's the 17th digit so is probably rubbish anyway and ought to be ignored.

Comment: The extra 5 at the end of my number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work from higher numbers to lower numbers to minimize cancellation:

```
var e = 1;
for(var k = 17; k > 0; --k) {
    e = 1 + e/k;
}
return e;
```

Evaluating the Taylor polynomial by Horner's rule even avoids the factorial and allows you to use more terms (won't make a difference beyond 17, though).

Comment: Note that you can even re-write this to eliminate all divides but one, on systems where a divide is considerably more costly than a multiply.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see your number is the same as `Math.E` and even has a better precision.

2.7182818284590455

2.718281828459045

What is the problem after all?

Comment: Well I checked on WolframAlpha and after the 5 on Euler's constant comes a 2 but on mine it comes a 5. I was afraid that'd be too inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

With javascript, you cannot calculate *e* this way due to the level of precision of javascript computations.  See http://www.javascripter.net/faq/accuracy.htm for more info.

To demonstrate this problem please take a look at the following fiddle which calculates e with n starting at 50000000, incrementing n by 1 every 10 milliseconds:

http://jsfiddle.net/q8xRs/1/

Answer (score 0):

I like using integer values to approximate real ones.
Possible approximations of e in order of increasing accuracy are:
11/4
87/32
23225/8544
3442297523731/1266350489376

That last one is fairly accurate, equating to:
2.7182818284590452213260834432
which doesn't diverge from [wikipedia's value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) till the 18th:
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995

So there's that, if you're interested.